# Conversion of the binary data string of image file to a Blob

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert the data retrieved from an API to a `Blob` to be able to display it as an image on my page.
In the response, I get the data string which in the browser console looks like shown below. I assume that it is just a binary data of a file (it looks like it to me).

[image: Binary data string in the console]

I use this code to convert the string to the `Blob`:

```js
const convertBinaryToBlob = (binary: string, contentType: string): Blob => {
  const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    uInt8Array[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
};
```

It gets generated fine, as well as the `Blob` object URL, so I am able to put it as the `src` of an image. The problem is that the image cannot be displayed by the browser because it contains some errors.
What's the issue in here? How am I able to get it working?

When I test it using `curl`, I use this command:

```sh
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000/images/file/6' -H 'accept: */*' --output img.png
```

The output file is working without any problem. Response headers from the `curl`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 20:05:30 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-type: image/png
content-length: 3099363
last-modified: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 18:12:08 GMT
etag: 38e1bb48826eab759ab7220bc805124b
```

Comment: I've used [this as a temporary solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70564656/5905695). I am returning base64 directly from the API. But I am still looking for a solution to the problem described.

Answer (score 0):

A blob isn't a valid image source. You have to convert the binary data to base64 so you can pass it as an image source.

Replace binaryString with your binary data.

```js
const encodeBase64 = (data) => {
    return Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
}

var base64EncodedStr = encodeBase64(decodeURI(encodeURIComponent(binaryString)));
var src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64EncodedStr ;
```

Set your image source equal to the src variable.

Also png could be another image format.

Code composed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982712/convert-binary-data-to-base64-with-javascript) post

Comment: I've used the code provided by you, but unfortunately, it still shows that the file contains errors. Also, as the VS Code has shown me that methods like `btoa` and `unescape` are deprecated, I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733727/5905695) which at the first sight returns the same base64, but it does not work either.

Comment: My bad i've updated the deprecated methods. When  you tried it yourself did you replace unescape with decodeURI? That should be the function that prevents errors...

Comment: I did not, but the first code you have sent did not work either. Now I've copied the code after your edit and it shows the same error. So I think that it's not the issue.